# Moving caption to the left

Tags: floats, captions, two-column, els-cas

I just add a figure but the caption starts on the middle, how can I fix it?
I tried with `\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}` but it did not move the caption.
I want it to start more on the left side

Here there is a minimal reproducible example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure*}[pos=h!]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{example-image}
    \caption{Change in number of trips respect to first week of each year, treatment vs. control.}
    \label{FIG:1}
\end{figure*}
\blindtext[2]


\end{document}
```

[image: The caption is wrong]

Thanks

Edit: Fixed the example

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Does the graphic take up the full width of the textblock? Please advise.

Comment: This is **not** a reproducible example. First, we do not have your image original image. Second, the code produce errors (at least to me) even removing the image. Please use as image just "example-image" or other supplied by the `mwe` package  (that everybody can use) and then check again that you posted is really compilable as is.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I fixed the reproducible example (I hope)

Comment: Try remove * in `figure` environment: `\\begin{figure}[pos=h!]` ... `\end{figure}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the document class (`cas-dc`) doesn't calculate the width available for captions of `figure*` environments correctly. Unfortunately (for me), much of the code in `cas-dc` employs LaTeX3 syntax, which I don't understand well enough to figure out where exactly the mistake occurs. Instead, I'll offer the following work-around.

- Find the files `cas-dc.cls` and `cas-common.sty` in your TeX distribution. Copy them into your current working directory and name them `cas-dc-mod.cls` and `cas-common-mod.sty`, respectively.
- Open the file `cas-dc-mod.cls` in an editor; the program you use to edit your tex files will do fine. First, change `\def\RCSfile{cas-dc}` on line 20 to `\def\RCSfile{cas-dc-mod}`. (This step is of the "good housekeeping" variety. Its purpose is to avoid getting a (in this case) harmless LaTeX warning.) Second, locate the instruction

  ```
  \RequirePackage{cas-common}
  ```

  (It's on line 90 in my copy of the file.) Change it to

  ```
  \RequirePackage{cas-common-mod}
  ```

  and save and close the file.
- Open the file `cas-common-mod.sty` in a text editor. First, change `\def\RCSfile{cas-common}` on line 20 to `\def\RCSfile{cas-common-mod}`. (Again, a step of the "good housekeeping" variety.) Second, locate the line

  ```
  \RenewDocumentEnvironment { figure* } { O{width=\textwidth} }
  ```

  (It's on line 1993 in my file.) A few lines down, locate the following line:

  ```
  \cs_set_eq:NN \@makecaption \__make_fig_caption:nn
  ```

  (It's on line 2001 in my copy of the file.) Comment out this line and save and close the file.
- Finally, in your main tex file, you need to

  - change the document class name from `cas-dc` to `cas-dc-mod`,
  - load the `caption` package in the preamble, and
  - insert the following instructions immediately after `\begin{figure*}`:

    ```
    \captionsetup{justification=raggedright,
                  singlelinecheck=false,
                  font=sf, labelfont=bf}
    ```
  - repeat the preceding step for all further `figure*` environments in your document.

If this sounds a bit tedious to you, I'd say you're right. But I'm confident the solution works. :-)

Comment: From OP code follows, that it use one column version of `cas-dc` document, so it not need to use `figure*` environment. (two column require `twocolumn` option at loading document class). However, your workaround is very valuable (+1) !

Comment: @Zarko - Thanks! It's certainly true that the current version of the OP's posting does *not* mention that a two-column layout is in use; for a one-column layout, the unstarred `figure` environment (for which the line width calculation is not messed up) should definitely be used. The OP's initial, meanwhile over-written, version of the posting, however, did mention that a two-column layout was in use; in that context, employing a `figure*` environment to generate a full-width float makes eminent sense.